# Laravel / Eloquent: Search for rows by value in polymorphed table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relation, polymorphism

I'm stuck at the moment and hope someone can give me a hand. I'm using a polymorphic relation and want to search my database for rows that fulfill conditions in the "parent" and the "child" table.

To get concrete, one small example. Given the following structure I e.g. want to look for a property with price "600" and rooms "3". Is there a way to do that with eloquent?

### Tables

**Table properties (parent)**

- id
- price
- details_type       [can be "Apartment" or "Parcel"]
- details_id

**Table apartments (child)**

- id
- rooms

**Table parcels (child)**

- id
- ... (does not have a "rooms" column)

### Relationships

**Class Property**

```
public function details() {
  return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**Classes Apartment + Parcel**

```
public function property() {
  return $this->morphMany('Property', 'details')
}
```

### What I tried

A lot, really. But somehow I'm always doing something wrong or missing something. The solutions that, in my opinion should work are either:

```
Property::with(array('details' => function($query) {
                  $query->where('rooms', 3);
             }));
```

or

```
Property::with('details')
        ->whereHas('details', function($query) {
            $query->where('rooms', '=', '3');
        });
```

But in both cases I get the following FatalError.:

```
Class name must be a valid object or a string
```

Has anyone of you already had a similar problem? Thank you very much for any kind of hint.

Answer (score 5):

Let's start with your naming convention:

```
public function detail() // It relates to a single object
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

And

```
public function properties() // It relates to several objects
{
    return $this->morphMany('Property', 'details')
}
```

Then you would be able to do this:

```
$properties = Property::whereHas('details', function($q)
{
    $q->where('rooms', '=', '3');
})
->where('price', '=', 600)
->get();
```

Please note that this will never return a Parcel, since there isn't a parcel with a room.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Your suggested solution is what I thought too. However doing that I get an error: `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
Class name must be a valid object or a string`. It seems to me that `whereHas` does not support polymorphic relations yet.

Comment: Ah, I now realize what the problem is. Eloquent does not support Eager Loading of Polymorphic Childs as of yet. Eloquent is only able to Eager Load Polymorphic Parents. I would advise you to use the Query Builder instead and do it the raw way. :)